# Moodle - no listening sockets available shutting down

Tags: apache, moodle

I've downloaded `MOODLE 3.5+` for windows, when I press `Start Moodle.exe` I keep getting this message

> 2018-06-13 17:57:54 3636 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 10.1.28-MariaDB) st
>   arting as process 4228 ...
>   (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
>   s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
>   s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>
> AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> AH00015: Unable to open logs

I've changed the port number to 8080 by editing `listen 8080` in `httpd.conf` file.
and it shows error again.

I've tested and found that no process (or firewall) listening to these port numbers (using task manager).

So how to choose port number?

Comment: This is likely due to MySQL being started without good permissions

Comment: `could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80` is not an issue with MySQL.